# Converting datetime.datetime to timestamp(millisecond) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

I am pulling some data from a MSSQL database in my python 2.7 code.

The timestamp column stored in the database is in proper unix timestamp (1521856800.000) up-to millisecond, lets say which translate to 2018-03-23 01:00:00.000.

while fetching this data in Python, I am getting the output in datetime, Seems like it is truncating minutes, second and millisecond information due to absolute hour.

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 23, 1, 0)
```

Any help i can convert it back to 2018-03-23 01:00:00.000 or 1521856800.000 ?

Comment: I think you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Nothing is being truncated; `datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 23, 1, 0)` and `datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 23, 1, 0, 0, 0)` are just different ways to spell equal values. The `repr` is just giving you the shortest way to construct tht value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual problem here. The `datetime` object you have is not truncated in any way.

What's happening is that `datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 23, 1, 0)` means the exact same thing as `datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 23, 1, 0, 0, 0)`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 23, 1, 0) == datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 23, 1, 0, 0, 0)
True
```

The `minute`, `second`, and `microsecond` parameters to the `datetime` constructor have default values of `0`, so leaving them off does the same thing as passing `0`.

In other words, this is basically the same as the fact that `10.0` and `10.0000` are different ways of spelling the same `float`.

When you print out a `datetime` object's `repr`, it gives you the shortest way to construct the same object. That has no effect on the `timestamp()` (which is still exactly `1521856800.0`), or the `str` (`"2018-03-23 01:00:00"`), or on how it works with `strftime` or date arithmetic or anything else.